# MongoDB query using map-reduce/Aggregation?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongoose

I have simple data in mongo collection.It looks like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("52b73b1318a7be441dbf36b6"),
"nme" : "Vinod Kumar",
"unm" : "vkumar",
"cat" : ISODate("2013-12-22T19:18:43.873Z"),
"act" : [{
    "nme" : "test activity one",
    "dec" : "This is only about test activity",
    "gat" : ISODate("2013-12-25T19:17:00.873Z"),
    "cat" : ISODate("2013-12-22T19:18:43.873Z")
    }]
},

{
"_id" : ObjectId("52b73b1318a7be441dbf36b6"),
"nme" : "Manoj Kumar",
"unm" : "mkumar",
"cat" : ISODate("2013-12-22T19:18:43.873Z"),
"act" : [{
    "nme" : "test activity three",
    "dec" : "This is only about test activity",
    "gat" : ISODate("2013-12-25T19:17:00.873Z"),
    "cat" : ISODate("2013-12-20T19:18:43.873Z")
    },
        {
    "nme" : "test activity two",
    "dec" : "This is only about test activity",
    "gat" : ISODate("2013-12-25T19:17:00.873Z"),
    "cat" : ISODate("2013-12-21T19:18:43.873Z")
    }]
}
```

I want to get all act(activities) orderby cat(created time) along with (unm)username.I also want to add pagination feature so I would need limit and offset in query too.Finally I am expecting output:

```
        {
    "nme" : "test activity one",
    "dec" : "This is only about test activity",
    "gat" : ISODate("2013-12-25T19:17:00.873Z"),
    "cat" : ISODate("2013-12-22T19:18:43.873Z"),
    "unm" : "vkumar",
    },
        {
    "nme" : "test activity two",
    "dec" : "This is only about test activity",
    "gat" : ISODate("2013-12-25T19:17:00.873Z"),
    "cat" : ISODate("2013-12-21T19:18:43.873Z"),
    "unm" : "mkumar",
    },
        {
    "nme" : "test activity three",
    "dec" : "This is only about test activity",
    "gat" : ISODate("2013-12-25T19:17:00.873Z"),
    "cat" : ISODate("2013-12-20T19:18:43.873Z"),
    "unm" : "mkumar",
    }
```

I have 200000 records in this collection. Can anybody able to help me without suggesting creating activities collection separate.

Is there any workaround using aggregation framework if yes how would I do? As I need to use sort, skip and limit, I dont know how to do that with aggregation with optimal performance.

I tried map reduce but that would not help as map reduce will generate static results for each query and multiple users using application might conflict in result while using pagination (limit, skip).

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks

Here is my current query

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$c = $m->selectDB("test")->selectCollection("users");

$ops = array(
array(
    '$project' => array(
        "unm" => 1,
        "act" => 1
    )
),
array('$sort' => array('act.cat' => -1 )),
array('$limit' => 10),

);
$results = $c->aggregate($ops);
```

Comment: You can potentially use the [Aggregation Framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) in MongoDB 2.2+, but the output is limited to the maximum BSON document size (currently 16Mb). With 200,000 documents and a large number of activities in each document you will likely reach the limit and have to run more than one aggregation query. What do you need to do with the results of this query?  Seems like something you'd want further summarised (or perhaps you will limit the query by user name rather than finding all matches).

Comment: Hi Stennie, Many thanks for your response. I am trying to fetch all activities created by users order by time created. I want to display these results on activity page and possible pagination. It so difficult to find clue as I am new to mongo. I am sure there if there is some way to limit results per page the document size will not go more then 16 mb. Do you need anything more to know about?

Comment: After reading more about mapreduce i think mapreduce will not fit in my case. As map reduce is for background tasks and map reduce output will not be unique for each users. For example a users want to see all activities on page 1 and another users is on 2.Is there any other work around?

Comment: There is no issue with max doc size as you'll be paginating.  Use agg framework with $sort $skip and $limit.

Comment: Hi @AsyaKamsky Thanks to be part of this solution. Yes I finally tried aggregation, I tested with 80,000 rows and its taking time of 1.5 seconds. please see the php query in updated question. Is there any way to get better performance without caching page?

Comment: @Stennie Do you have any suggestion on this?

Comment: Do you have an index on the two fields you want to sort/paginate on? You said you want to sort by username - that's not in your query. Btw you don't need $project first - you can put it last, AF is smart enough not to pass through fields it doesn't need. But index is critical for good performance.

Comment: Hi @AsyaKamsky, I want to order by cat - which is created_at. As you can see act- Activities are array. How I would index array in mongo.

Comment: You index array the same way as non-array

Answer (score 0):

Here is answer of my own question. I now realised mongo have hidden powers :P

```
$m = new MongoClient();
$c = $m->selectDB("test")->selectCollection("users");

$ops = array(
array(
'$project' => array(
"unm" => 1,
"act" => 1
)
),
array('$unwind' => '$act'),
array('$match' => array('act.sta' => 1)), // if you want some extra queries. In my case I am checking if status of activity is 1
array('$sort' => array('act.cat' => -1 )), // sort by created time
array('$skip' => $page), // skip int variable
array('$limit' =>$config['per_page']), // limit int variable
);

$results = $c->aggregate($ops); 
print_r($results);
```